# unusual resolving of namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in .NET ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces

Working on a C# ASP.NET app using library

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

If I add this using:

```
using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

VS can resolve correctly `Application` as a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`

But it fails to resolve

```
Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

I would have to write the full path:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

I need to write the following extra include line to have VS to resolve the latter:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Can you give me an explanation about this?

thx

Comment: Server side Office automation is not supported. Check Microsoft KB article to learn why. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: Thx for sharing, I ll probaby have the server to start an exe app that will perform the automation. I hope it will solve the mentionned issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault` is not in the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.  It is in `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.  Put that in a using clause and you should be good to go.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
```

Comment: Nope, I had tried that first and it did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only need to define the first line

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

"Word" is actually a namespace allias, and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word is not a library, it's actually an object. Also since it is an allias you can use any name for it, so something like:

```
using W = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

would be valid as well, but you would have to use that namespace on your code, like:

```
W.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault
```